# View collision models in Drake

Tags: drake

Is there any way to view the collision models with Drake Visualizer without simply copying the model in the visual tag? I was trying to use a mesh as a collision model and I am unable to get collisions working with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of key points:

1. General meshes cannot be used for contact. The best you can hope for is using a `convex` mesh. Here's an example of the specification in an [sdf](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/parsing/test/sdf_parser_test/all_geometries_as_collision.sdf#L42). Here's the corresponding example in a [urdf](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/parsing/test/urdf_parser_test/all_geometries_as_collision.urdf#L35). They're both very similar.

   - It's worth emphasizing that the mesh must truly be convex; it won't be checked but lying will produce unexpected results.
2. If you're using `drake_visualizer` as your visualizer, you most likely have a call to `ConnectDrakeVisualizer`. That takes an optional argument where you can request it to visualize the collision (aka `Role::kProximity`) instead of the default visual (aka `Role::kIllustration`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Declaring the mesh as convex totally worked! Is there any good way to visualize the collison models in drake visualizer?

Comment: What Sean mentioned in point (2) should get you what you want - visualizing (only) the collisions by specifying `ConnectDrakeVisualizer(..., Role::kProximity)`. Have you had a chance to give that a whirl?

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically change the Role without having to set another scenegraph? I'd like to go back and forth between the contact model and the visual model while the simulation is on-going

Comment: Not currently. But the drake_visualizer implementation will go through a minor overhaul this quarter and I'm thinking about tweaking that -- making it easier to do exactly that. I'll post a link to an issue discussing proposals here.

Comment: See new Drake issue: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13673